# ggpredict error with lm_robust model including fixed effects and clustered standard errors

Tags: r, sjplot

I am running a regression on two independent variables and their interaction, along with district fixed effects and clustering the standard errors at the observation level using `lm_robust` command from `estimatr` (version 0.22.0) with R version 3.6.0.

I want to visualize the predicted regression results using the `plot` command from `ggpredict` (version 0.14.3) but am getting an error that appears to be due to the inclusion of the fixed effects.

The specific error I get is: 
`Error in X[, !beta_na, drop = FALSE] %*% coefs[!beta_na, ] : non-conformable arguments`

If I use `ggpredict` after running a regression that only clusters the standard errors but does not include fixed effects, the code runs just fine. I get the same error when using the wrapper commands from `sjPlot` instead of `ggpredict`.

Below is a MWE:

```
library(ggeffects)
library(estimatr)
library(sjPlot)
N <- 1000
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:N),
                 district = as.factor(rep(1:20, times = 50)),
                 x = rpois(N, lambda = 4),
                 y = rnorm(N),
                 z = factor(rbinom(N, 1, prob = 0.5)))

mod1 <- lm_robust(y ~ x*z,
                  clusters = id,
                  fixed_effects = ~district,
                  data = df)
summary(mod1)
predDF <- ggpredict(mod1, terms = c("x", "z")) # use ggpredict from ggeffects
plot_model(mod1, type = "pred", terms = c("x", "z")) # using plot_model from sjPlot
```

Wondering either how to get `ggeffects`/`sjPlot` to work `lm_robust` models containing both clustered standard errors and fixed effects - or alternative packages? I already switched from using `felm` in the `lfe` library for the fixed effects and clustering because `ggeffects` doesn't work on `felm` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be with `estimatr`'s predict method. See a similar discussion involving `plm` [here](https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/issues/121).

If we try to predict using `estimatr:::predict.lm_robust`, the same error is generated:

```r
library(ggeffects)
library(estimatr)
library(sjPlot)
N <- 1000
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:N),
                 district = as.factor(rep(1:20, times = 50)),
                 x = rpois(N, lambda = 4),
                 y = rnorm(N),
                 z = factor(rbinom(N, 1, prob = 0.5)))

mod1 <- lm_robust(y ~ x*z,
                  clusters = id,
                  fixed_effects = ~district,
                  data = df)

new_df <- data.frame(x = rep(0:10, 2), z = factor(c(rep(0, 11), rep(1, 11))))

predict(mod1, newdata = new_df)
#> Error in X[, !beta_na, drop = FALSE] %*% coefs[!beta_na, ]: non-conformable arguments
```

If it is not too onerous, you could do a workaround by fitting the fixed effects model in `lm()`, cluster the standard errors in the `ggeffects()` call. I know that estimating fixed effects with `lm()` is not ideal, but it works!

```r
mod1 <- lm(y ~ x*z + factor(district), data = df)

predDF <- ggpredict(mod1, c("x", "z"), 
                    vcov.fun = "vcovCL", 
                    vcov.type = "HC1",
                    vcov.args = list(cluster = df$id))

plot(predDF)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>